# Is shelve unsafe for read-only multiprocessing?

Tags: python, persistence, multiprocessing, shelve

The documentation of the `shelve` module makes the following claim under *Restrictions*:

> The shelve module does not support concurrent read/write access to shelved objects. **(Multiple simultaneous read accesses are safe.)**

As far as I can tell, this means that as long as I don't try to have multiple processes write to a single shelf at once, I should be in the clear. Multiple processes using the same shelf as a read-only cache should be safe. Right?

Apparently not. After some struggling, I ended up with a test case that appears to demonstrate some very bad behavior when reading asynchronously from the shelf. The following script:

1. Creates a `Shelf` and populates it with `"i" : 2*i` for `i` from 1 to 10.
2. Reads all those values back, to assure they got stored correctly.
3. Spawns processes to retrieve values for each key from the shelf file, and reports whether a value was retrieved or not.

   ```
   import multiprocessing
   import shelve

   SHELF_FILE = 'test.shlf'

   def store(key, obj):
       db = shelve.open(SHELF_FILE, 'w')
       db[key] = obj
       db.close()

   def load(key):
       try:
           db = shelve.open(SHELF_FILE, 'r')
           n = db.get(key)
           if n is not None:
               print('Got result {} for key {}'.format(n, key))
           else:
               print('NO RESULT for key {}'.format(key))
       except Exception as e:
           print('ERROR on key {}: {}'.format(key, e))
       finally:
           db.close()

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       db = shelve.open(SHELF_FILE, 'n') # Create brand-new shelf
       db.close()

       for i in range(1, 11): # populate the new shelf with keys from 1 to 10
           store(str(i), i*2)

       db = shelve.open(SHELF_FILE, 'r') # Make sure everything got in there.
       print(', '.join(key for key in db)) # Should print 1-10 in some order
       db.close()

       # read each key's value from the shelf, asynchronously
       pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
       for i in range(1, 11):
           pool.apply_async(load, [str(i)])
       pool.close()
       pool.join()
   ```

The expected output here would naturally be `2, 4, 6, 8` and so on up to 20 (in some order). Instead, arbitrary values cannot be retrieved from the shelf, and sometimes the request causes `shelve` to blow up altogether. The actual output looks like this: ("NO RESULT" lines indicate keys that returned `None`):

```
6, 7, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 10, 8, 9
ERROR on key 3: need 'c' or 'n' flag to open new db
ERROR on key 6: need 'c' or 'n' flag to open new db
Got result 14 for key 7
NO RESULT for key 10
Got result 2 for key 1
Got result 4 for key 2
NO RESULT for key 8
NO RESULT for key 4
NO RESULT for key 5
NO RESULT for key 9
```

My intuition, given the error messages, is that maybe external resources (maybe the `.dir` file?) aren't being flushed to disk appropriately (or maybe they're deleted by other processes?). Even then, I'd expect a slowdown as a process waited for the disk resource, rather than these "oh I guess it's not there" or "What are you talking about this isn't even a shelf file" results. And frankly I wouldn't expect there to be any writing to those files anyway, since the worker processes only use read-only connections...

Is there something I'm missing, or is `shelve` just outright unusable in multiprocessing environments?

This is Python 3.3 x64 on Windows 7, if that turns out to be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an alerting comment in `shelve.open()` documentation:

> Open a persistent dictionary. The filename specified is the base
>   filename for the underlying database. As a side-effect, an extension
>   may be added to the filename and more than one file may be created.

Try to pass a preopened shelve (instead of a filename) to the pool threads, and see if the behaviour changes. That said, I don't have a repro with 2.7, Win7-64 (an output is all messed up of course).

Comment: I had assumed that individual `Shelf` objects couldn't be passed to multiprocesses, but making this change does appear to immediately clean up all of the errors and failures in this simple case. Do you know if a `Shelf` is canonically safe to share between processes directly, or does it realistically need a `Manager` to ensure consistency?

Comment: That I don't know. My _guess_ is it is safe by itself (assuming no writes, of course).